# Google Apps Script - IF ELSE with multiple conditions combined with AND and OR

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for advice on how to write this better. Source is Google Sheets. I have another few IF ELSE statements so looking to consolidate code.

I also want another condition where if `employed == "NO" && school == "NO"` and Postcode does not match those listed it sends a separate email.

Code truncated to best address specific question.

```
   if (status == "" && postcode == "4518" || postcode == "4519" || postcode == "4550" || postcode == "4551" || postcode == "4552" || postcode == "4575" && employed == "NO" && school == "NO") {

       MailApp.sendEmail(
            // to email 1
       }
       ); 
    } 

   else if (status == "" && postcode == "4556" || postcode == "4557" || postcode == "4558" || postcode == "4564" && employed == "NO" && school == "NO") {

       MailApp.sendEmail(
            // to email 2   
       }
       ); 
    }
}
```

I could potentially have a second dataset with two columns, Postcode and Email Address. Where a postcode MATCH is found it sends off to the email address listed in Column B. If no match found and `employed == "NO" && school == "NO"` then a fallback email is sent. No idea how to write that nor how to start researching that.

Comment: How about something like `postcode in ["4518", "4519", "4550",...]`

Comment: Thanks for your input Robin, I did try your code, it failed however I believe it was to do with something else. I got the code to a stable state with nesting of IF ELSE statements in its original `postcode == "4518" || postcode == "4519"` form. Its live now so I am reluctant to go back and test. I'll do so on the next project and hopefully your suggestion helps someone else. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple things -

1. I see a few variables that are common for both conditions; **status**, **employed** & **school**. Perhaps you could put them under a default/primary `IF` condition
2. Introduce `indexOf` within the data array (refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf))

You could accordingly refactor the code as below -

```
function myFunction() {

  var postcode = '4558';
  var status = 'whatever';
  var employed = 'foo';
  var school = 'bar';

  var postcode1 = ["4518","4519","4550","4551","4552","4575"];
  var postcode2 = ["4556","4557","4558","4564"];
  if (status == "" && employed == "NO" && school == "NO") {
    if(postcode1.indexOf(postcode) !== -1) {
      Logger.log("email 1");
    } else if (postcode2.indexOf(postcode) !== -1) {
      Logger.log("email 2");
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `postcode1` & `postcode2` are simply 2 different data arrays that can also be used using the usual Spreadsheet services.

Hope this helps.